# Sorted Insertion in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, sorting, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a code in to insert a node containing an integer variable into a doubly linked list which is either already sorted or has no elements in it. I've been provided with a file to test whether my code works. My code is compiling just fine, it's just that the test fails my code every time.

Here's the code for my sorted insertion

```
void List<T>::insertSorted(T item)
{
    ListItem<T> *temp, *temp2;
    ListItem<T>* a=new ListItem<T>(item);   //creates a node with our input item

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=a;              //if the list is empty, set head equal to the new
        //node
    }


    //Following two conditions check whether head is the sole item in the list
    //(i.e head->next==NULL), and then insert our node in it accordingly.

    else if(head->value > item && head->next==NULL) 
    {
        a->next=head;
        head->prev=a;
        head=a;
    }

    else if(head->value < item  && head->next==NULL)
    {
        head->next=a;
        a->prev=head;
    }

    //This piece checks whether our list has more than one nodes, and adds
    //the input node accordingly.
    else if(head->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp=head->next;   //here i'm taking two consecutive nodes
        //which in the first case are head->next and head;
        temp2=head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            //if our value can be sandwiched between two nodes then do this
            if(temp->value > item && temp2->value < item)
            {
                temp2->next=a;
                a->prev=temp2;
                a->next=temp;
                temp->prev=a;
                break;
            }
            //go to the next two consecutive nodes
            temp=temp->next;
            temp2=temp2->next;

            //if one of our node is null (i.e we've reached the end of
            //the list, do the following
            if(temp2->value <= item && temp==NULL)
            {
                temp2->next=a;
                a->prev=temp2;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This apparently is wrong. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm somewhat of a novice to programming, and believe I've been trying to do that.

Comment: `temp2->next=a; a->prev=temp2; a->next=temp; temp->prev=a;` <- if you were using some meaningful names for your variables, it would help you a lot while trying to understand what is your code actually doing.

Comment: If the new item to insert is smaller than the head item, it doesn't matter if there is only one node in the list or not, just make the new item the new head. Also, I recommend you keep track of the last node in the list as well, the tail, to easily insert at the end.

Comment: I'm picking pointers to two consecutive nodes and checking whether our node can be placed right between them. temp is the node right next to temp2, and the value that temp holds is larger than temp2. I agree I could've named them better, but is there something wrong with the code itself?

Comment: @ Toms, I didn't notice the big 'tick' right next to the answers. I've done that with all my questions now.

Comment: @Toms Please do not ask people to vote or accept your answers in the future.

Comment: @Andrew Barber really sorry. i noticed he has not accepted any answers for all his questions. thats why i mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not intializing to `NULL` the `next` and `prev` pointers of new node `a` directly in the function. Following modification in insertSorted function makes code working perfectly for me

```
 else if(head->value == item  && head->next==NULL)
 {
                head->next=a;
                a->prev=head;
 }

     //This piece checks whether our list has more than one nodes, and adds
     //the input node accordingly.
else if(head->next!=NULL)
{
     temp=head;   
      temp2=head;   //keep track of previous element in the loop
      while(temp!=NULL)
      {
            //if our value can be sandwiched between two nodes then do this
            if(temp->value < item)
            {
                 temp2 = temp;
             temp = temp ->next;
        }
        else
        {
             //from temp onward all numbers will be grater than item. so inserting before item
              a->next = temp;
            a->prev = temp->prev;
            temp->prev = a;
            if (temp == head)
            {
                 head = a;
            }
            else// if temp not head then there is a previous element assign previos elemnts next to a
                 {                  
                temp2->next = a;
                 }
            break;
        }
        }
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            temp2->next=a;
            a->prev = temp2;
         }
     }
```

Please check

Only problem i found was there is no checking for this condition  `if(head->value == item && head->next==NULL)`

Comment: If you're going to initialise to null, I suggest you do it in the constructor rather than like this. Remembering to initialise to null each time is highly error prone.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that the constructor for the ListItem class initialized the next and prev pointers to NULL.

    template <class T>
    struct ListItem
    {
        T value;
        ListItem<T> *next;
        ListItem<T> *prev;

        ListItem(T theVal)
        {
            this->value = theVal;
            this->next = NULL;
            this->prev = NULL;
        }
    };

Comment: whats your error. i am getting anwser sorted correctly. is your problem in sorting or in inserting element. what error? run time?

Comment: The problem is in sorting. I've been provided with a code that tests my implementation. I think it checks for border cases. Whenever I test my code, it fails it.

Comment: check my edit and add that condition if(head->value == item && head->next==NULL).

Comment: The code that tests my implementation is rather large so I'm not sure if I should post it.

Comment: @ Toms, I added that condition and it still failed it. I'm beginning to suspect that the testing code is faulty.

Comment: No there are some mistakes. i modified the code. Ask if you have any doubts

Comment: i think you got it where to add the modified code. in your code after first two if loops in the function should be overwritten by this code

Comment: The test failed this code as well, but I was randomly tweaking my code and testing them and caught I seg fault. I added the condition to circumvent that and my code works perfectly now.
At any rate, thanks a lot. :)